# Where to get novacom package from

Tags: 14.10, hp-touchpad

For working with my HP Touchpad, I now need the novacom package for Linux 64, again. Sadly, when searching, all palm sources seem to be extinct. I tried building from source, but their build system is a little flawed.

Does anyone know, where to find the package outside of palm pages?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the exact package now turned out some mirrors: `palm-novacom_1.0.64_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

The files are no longer available at Palm's website. I found them here: http://download2.polytechnic.edu.na/pub4/sourceforge/b/bi/bioinfoserv/Packages/Version5.0-YuleFlying/WebOS/2.1/

Answer (score -1):

Novacom is available from The Palm Developer Network.  Which also have good information on how to install.  To download see the Palm Developer [website](https://developer.palm.com/index.php?id=1585&view=article).

Once on the page, scroll down to Number 5, and there you can download Novacom.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, probably the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i palm-novacom_1.0.64_amd64.deb
```

Keep in mind that you may have to install per-requisits, so make sure you look at the website.

You can also download from [Here](https://copy.com/UYUQXoKtLaZMMjJp)

Comment: The palm website is no longer available.

Comment: I just downloaded the file from Palm.  I uploaded to my copy account.  I've added the link to the answer.